# substrings with Balanced parentheses

Tags: string, algorithm, parentheses

The following question was asked to my friend in an interview : given a string consisting only of '(' and ')'. find total number of substrings with balanced parentheses Note: the input string is already balanced.

The only solution i can think of this problem is brute force which takes n^3 time. Is there a faster solution possible.If there is then i would also like to know the build up to that approach.

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: not done any code right now i can just think of brute force right now which is   for each substring check it has balanced paretheses or not . checking will take O(length) time using a stack . I thought of thinking algo first and then writing code

Comment: Yes, you can do better than that.  Try thinking recursively (though you can refactor to an iterative solution pretty easily.)

Comment: Do you now how to check a string for balance? If yes, then you can easily get O(n^2) solution

Comment: Also see: http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/43944

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume the final result will be in an integer R. You should scan from left to right on the string Then, you should keep a stack Z, and update it as you scan from left to right.

You should initially push a 0 onto Z. When you encounter a '(' at index i, you should push 0 onto S. When you encounter a ')' at index i, you should increment R by (T * (T+1) / 2), T being the top element of Z. Then you should pop T, and increment **the new top element** by 1.

Once the scan is complete, you should increment R for one more time by (T * (T+1) / 2), as there is still an element T in Z that we initially put.

The scan using the stack Z should take **linear time**. Below is a not-so-efficient Python implementation that is hopefully easy to understand.

```
def solve(s):
    R = 0
    Z = [0]
    for i in range(0, len(s)):
        if s[i] == '(':
            Z.append(0)
        else:
            R += Z[-1] * (Z[-1] + 1) / 2
            Z = Z[:-1]
            Z[-1] += 1
    R += Z[-1] * (Z[-1] + 1) / 2
    return R
```

The idea behind the incrementing R is as follows. Basically you keep the number of the **consecutive** same-level balanced strings until are about to get out of that level. Then, when you are about to go to a higher level(i.e. when we **know** there won't be any other same-level and consecutive substring, we update the solution.

The value of T * (T + 1) / 2 can be understood if you think about the intervals a bit differently. Let's enumerate those consecutive same-level balanced substrings from 1 to T. Now, picking a balanced substrings using these is basically picking a starting and ending point for our larger substring. If we pick substring #1 as our starting point, there are T other substrings we may pick as the ending point. For #2, there are (T-1), and so on. Basically there are T*(T+1)/2 different intervals we can pick as a valid balanged substring, which is why we increment R by that value.

The final increment operation we apply to R is just to not omit the outermost level.

Comment: time complexity of your approach sir??

Comment: @suraj Well all you do is a scan through the string. If you use a proper stack (i.e. unlike using a list like I did) then all you do inside each iteration of the loop takes constant time. Hence, the complexity is linear in terms of the length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple algorithm that would solve your problem. Note that it doesn't look for nested balanced parentheses.

```
function TestAlgorithm(testString, resultCounter)
{
    if (!resultCounter)
        resultCounter = 0;

    var startIndex = testString.indexOf('(');

    if (startIndex === -1)
        return resultCounter;

    var endIndex = testString.indexOf(')', startIndex)

    if (endIndex === -1)
        return resultCounter;

    var newTestString = testString.substring(endIndex);

    return TestAlgorithm(newTestString, ++resultCounter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every substring that's in scope begins with a '('. So my non-recursive approach would be:

```
total = 0
while string is not empty {
    count valid substrings beginning here -- add to total
    trim leading '(' and trailing ')' from string
    trim leading ')' and trailing '(' from string if present
}
```

`count valid substrings beginning here` can be done by stepping through char by char, incrementing a counter when you see '(' and decrementing when you see ')'. When a decrement results in zero, you're at the closing ')' of a balanced substring.